# VBA codes could not run in marco enabled file type

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry that I am new to VBA, thanks to all the experts here I am able to copy some of the codes and modify them to suit my needs. Basically, they are just a couple of command buttons which carry out various functions. It work out fine in my excel 2010. However, when I try to save the file in my another computer with Excel 2007 (Confirmed that vba is running), a message popup saying

"The following Features cannot be saved in a macro-free workbooks:

VB Project

To save a file with these features, click no, and then choose a macro-enabled file type..."

Even I clicked no and then save it as xlsm. When I opened the file, all the vba codes are disabled. I just wonder whether it is due to any line of the following codes that could not be run in excel 2007. Many thanks for your help!

Apologies for the codes being a mess.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

' Defines variables
Dim Wb1 As Workbook, Wb2 As Workbook
' Disables screen updating to reduce flicker
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' Sets Wb1 as the current (destination) workbook
Set Wb1 = ThisWorkbook
' Sets Wb2 as the defined workbook and opens it - Update filepath / filename     as required
Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open("\\new_admin\MASTER_FILE.xlsx")
' Sets LastRow as the first blank row of Wb1 Sheet1 based on column A (requires at least header if document is otherwise blank)
    lastrow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
' With workbook 2
        With Wb2
' Activate it
            .Activate
' Activate the desired sheet - Currently set to sheet 1, change the number         accordingly
            .Sheets(1).Activate
' Copy the used range of the active sheet
            .ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
        End With
' Then with workbook 1
            With Wb1.Sheets(1)
' Activate it
                .Activate
' Select the first blank row based on column A
                .Range("A1").Select
' Paste the copied data
                .Paste
            End With
' Close workbook 2
    Wb2.Close
' Re-enables screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

' Defines variables
Dim Wb1 As Workbook, Wb2 As Workbook
' Disables screen updating to reduce flicker
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' Sets Wb1 as the current (destination) workbook
Set Wb1 = ThisWorkbook
' Sets Wb2 as the defined workbook and opens it - Update filepath / filename as required
Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Accom_Master_File.xlsx")
' Sets LastRow as the first blank row of Wb1 Sheet1 based on column A (requires at least header if document is otherwise blank)
    lastrow = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
' With workbook 2
        With Wb2
' Activate it
            .Activate
' Activate the desired sheet - Currently set to sheet 1, change the number accordingly
            .Sheets(1).Activate
' Copy the used range of the active sheet
            .ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
        End With
' Then with workbook 1
            With Wb1.Sheets(2)
' Activate it
                .Activate
' Select the first blank row based on column A
                .Range("A1").Select
' Paste the copied data
                .Paste
            End With
' Close workbook 2
    Wb2.Close
' Re-enables screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wkb As Workbook
Set wkb = ThisWorkbook

wkb.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B:C").Delete xlUp

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(2).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(1).Insert
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(3).Delete

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Dim dicKey As String
Dim dicValues As String
Dim dic
Dim data
Dim x(1 To 35000, 1 To 24)
Dim j As Long
Dim count As Long
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 data = Range("A2:X" & lastrow) ' load data into variable
         With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
                For i = 1 To UBound(data)
                     If .Exists(data(i, 2)) = True Then 'test to see if the key exists
                         x(count, 3) = x(count, 3) & ";" & data(i, 3)
                         x(count, 8) = x(count, 8) & ";" & data(i, 8)
                         x(count, 9) = x(count, 9) & ";" & data(i, 9)
                         x(count, 10) = x(count, 10) & ";" & data(i, 10)
                         x(count, 21) = x(count, 21) & ";" & data(i, 21)
                     Else
                        count = count + 1
                        dicKey = data(i, 2) 'set the key
                        dicValues = data(i, 2) 'set the value for data to be stored
                        .Add dicKey, dicValues
                        For j = 1 To 24
                          x(count, j) = data(i, j)
                        Next j
                     End If
                  Next i

          End With

             Rows("2:300").EntireRow.Delete
          Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).Resize(count - 1, 24).Value = x

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()

If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then Selection.AutoFilter

ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select

With Selection
.AutoFilter
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="ACTIVE"
.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="NUMBERS"
.Offset(1, 0).Select

End With

Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim rVis As Range

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For Each ws In Worksheets
    Do Until ws.Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlVisible).count = ws.Rows.count
  Set rVis = ws.Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlVisible)
  If rVis.Row = 1 Then
    ws.Rows(rVis.Areas(1).Rows.count + 1 & ":" & rVis.Areas(2).Row -     1).Delete
  Else
    ws.Rows("1:" & rVis.Row - 1).Delete
  End If
Loop
  Next ws
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   Dim LR As Long
LR = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Rows(LR).Copy
Rows(LR + 2).Insert

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()

Columns("A").Delete

    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

Range("X2:X" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[+1]=""PAYING"",     VLOOKUP(RC[-23],'Sheet2'!R1C1:R20000C8,8,0),""PENDING"")"

Range("Y2:Y" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-24],'Sheet2'!R1C1:R20000C8,2,0), ""PENDING"")"

Range("Z2:Z" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=(LEN(RC[-24])-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-24], "";"", """"))+1)*1200"

Range("AA2:AA" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-26],'Sheet3'!R2C2:R220C4,2,0)"

Range("AB2:AB" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-27],'Sheet3'!R2C2:R220C4,3,0)"

Range("AC2:AC" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-28],'Sheet4'!R1C1:R30C3,2,0),"""")"

Range("AD2:AD" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-29],'Sheet4'!R1C4:R30C6,2,0),"""")"

Columns("X:AD").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Sheets(1).Columns(24).NumberFormat = "@"
Sheets(1).Columns(25).NumberFormat = "@"
Sheets(1).Columns(29).NumberFormat = "@"
Sheets(1).Columns(30).NumberFormat = "@"

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()

Sheet1.Cells.Clear

End Sub
```

Comment: Please check if the macro options are enabled in Excel 2007. I remember facing the same problem.At that time the problem was Macro options and supporting add-ons were disabled.

Answer (score 1):

When something like this happens to me I just start up a new workbook and save explicitly in .xls or .xlsm format and then copy and paste my module or class code into new modules and classes in the new workbook. `-- cannot post comments yet so if this doesn't help i shall delete this answer.`